# Error:Could not download junit.jar (junit:junit:4.12): No cached version available for offline mode

Tags: android-studio, gradle

See the error underlined and also the only blue screen is available in the middle. I can't see phone preview of my project. Please help me

[image: see the error underlined and also the only blue screen is available in the middle i can't see phone preview of my project please help me]

gradle sync failed

Answer (score 6):

Go to **File - Other settings - Default settings**

on default settings dialog. search for " **global gradle settings**"

uncheck **"offline work"**

click **"Ok"**

(Connect to Internet) Go to **"Build"  - "clean Project"**